# Como puedo redireccionar al index y luego mostrar modal?

Tags: jquery

estoy intentando que al  registro ser exitoso, se rediriga al index y muestre un modal en el que está el login, pero no logro.
Con el código como está solo me abre el modal del login pero en la misma página de registro. He probado con windows.location pero solo me manda al index sin abrir el modal.
Alguna sugerencia? de antemano gracias.

```
 $('#registro').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();        

        var datos = $(this).serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: datos,
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                var resultado = data;                
                if(resultado.respuesta == 'exito'){
                    swal(
                        'Correcto',
                        'Guardado correctamente',
                        'success'
                    ).then(function() {                    
                        $('#amodal').trigger('click');
                    });
                } else {
                    swal(
                        'Error!',
                        'El numero de identificacion, telefono o email, ya existe',
                        'error'
                    )
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: Puedes agregar mas código para entender bien como esta estructurado?

Comment: El codigo es ese, lo demas no viene a colacion, el asunto está en el .then del swal... ahi es donde o redirecciono al index o abro el modal (es lo que hago con el trigger). El problema es q quiero hacer las dos cosas, pero no encuentro como

Comment: en el event `.then` debes redireccionar al `login` y ya en el login tienes que validar que viene de la pantalla del registro con la **validación del registro exitoso** después de esa validación activas el modal cuando llegue al login, de otra forma es imposible

Comment: La validacion del registro exitoso es lo q está en if(resultado.respuesta == 'exito') y luego ejecuta el swal, me dices q cree otra funcion?

Comment: Alguna vez usaste **localStorage**?

Comment: Si claro, pero no soy pro.

Comment: No es difícil aprenderlo tampoco

Comment: Ok, y como me sugieres q lo haga con localstorage?

Comment: Como te lo explique hace rato ya creando una variable en `localStorage` cuando el registro es exitoso, despues del redireccionamiento al `login` validas que exista esa variable y activas por `js` el click de la etiqueta que abre el modal que necesitas mostrar, pero ps si pusieras el **código** completo de lo que estas haciendo sería mas facil mostrarte como lo haces, por que creo que no es muy claro por aá y mucho menos con el código que esta publicado

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo. El codigo completo es demasiado extenso y esta dividido, esta el html donde esta el modal q tiene el login, el ingreso de datos a mysql y esta funcion de js para la notificacion en sweetalert y la redireccion. Dime q te muestro para q tengas mas luz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código actual quedaría así

```js
$('#registro').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();        

  var datos = $(this).serializeArray();

  $.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: datos,
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var resultado = data;                
      if(resultado.respuesta == 'exito'){
        swal(
         'Correcto',
         'Guardado correctamente',
         'success'
        ).then(function() {                    
         // $('#amodal').trigger('click'); // esto ya no va
         // creamos una variable en el localStorage para posteriormente validar en el login
         localStorage.validacionRegistro = true;
         location.href = 'login.html'; // redireccionamos a la url del login
        });
      } else {
        swal(
         'Error!',
         'El numero de identificacion, telefono o email, ya existe',
         'error'
        )
      }
    }
  })
});
```

En el template o html que se tenga del login agregamos esta validación con js

```html
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   // se verifica que si existe la variable del localStorage agregada
   // previamente desde la funcion del registro me dispare el click del modal
   if(localStorage.validacionRegistro){
    $('#amodal').trigger('click'); // el ID #amodal debe existir en el html del login
    // por ultimo podemos eliminar la variable del localStorage
    delete locaStorage.validacionRegistro;
   }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tu respuesta, funciona parcialmente. Si ejecuta el trigger y abre el modal, el problema es q al parecer no esta borrando la variable del localStorage asi q el trigger se sigue abriendo todo el tiempo. Pero creo q estamos cerca de lograrlo

Comment: agregaste la linea `delete locaStorage.validacionRegistro;`?

Comment: Si claro. Me sale en consola esto Uncaught ReferenceError: locaStorage is not defined at HTMLDocument.

Comment: aaaa claro es que no es `locaStorage` es `localStorage` jajajajja

Comment: Con eso ya debería de funcionar y no mostrar el modal siempre

Comment: hahahaha q novatada, por no leer. Gracias miles amigo

Comment: La idea es que hallas aprendido el concepto y el uso de `localStorage`

Comment: Asi es, igual seguire aprendiendo; muchas gracias, ya quedo funcionando como queria.